# Signature is invalid when I call Flickr API flickr.people.getPhotos to retrieving private photos of user

Tags: android, flickr

I am trying to develop a android application which access private photos of user. 
I am able to retrieve the minitoken and using the minitoken iam getting auth_token also. 
After getting the auth_token, I am generating the MD5 signature with
`{api_secret}api_key{api_key}auth_token{auth_token}methodflickr.people.getPhotosuserid{userid}`
When I try to call the method `flickr.people.getPhotos` using the url construct:
`http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPhotos&api_key={api_key}&user_id={uid}&auth_token={auth_token}&api_sig={api_sign}` 

 it is returning error as invalid signature.
Did anyone face same problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'format' parameter is missing in the call. If you are getting Invalid Signature error it means you are not creating signature in proper way.

Rest you can also check here :
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.people.getPhotos